# Shimano J-Kit installation

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

I'll soon be installing the BR-MT410 and BL-M4100 using the "easy hose joint system" (I assume) J-kit. [The instructions](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/MBDBR01/DM-MBDBR01-01-ENG.pdf) look straight forward but i still have some questions.

1. The caliper and hoses come attached and prefilled. Oil will leak I guess if you cut the hose and press in the connector insert? But its still installable after this without the need of bleeding (or at least its designed this way)?
2. The lever should be in a vise when inserting the cut cable with the connection port facing upward. The cable is installed on the bike already? So i should just unmount the lever from the bars and bring the bike next to the vise? Any other practical ways of doing this while keeping the bike mounted in the workstand?
3. Why is there a separate olive included (shown on pictures on webshop)? The easy hose joint system has the olive in the lever already.
4. I do not have the TL-BH62. Will cut using a cable cutter tool with sharp knife and hammer in the insert using the yellow press block from shimano. Any tips?

Answer (score 4):

The easy joint or J-kit is nice and simplifies installation. However, most bikes I've installed them on ended up with hoses too long--especially the front brake--and this situation requires trimming the hose. This process removes the factory installed insert. If you've already installed the lever on to the hose, the pre installed olive is toast as well. This is what the package of olive and insert is included for in the box--trimming the hose.

To answer your specific questions: Number 1: Yes a minimal amount of oil may seep after the hose is trimmed. Keeping it upright and still really minimizes the loss of oil. I've had excellent luck not having to bleed, even after trimming the hose. Shimano levers are designed to tolerate a bit of air and have the system function normally. It's when there is air in the line or at the caliper when poor braking is experienced.

Number 2: The lever position for installing the hose can be handled by a simple hand clamp that will grip a section of the handlebar to the inside while it's end holds fast the round bar clamp horizontally, making the connection face up. You can also slip lever clamp over something round secured in a vertical orientation allowing the connection to face up. I've used the handle of a nearby bench vise for this. Turn it vertical and secure it from slipping down with a vise grip. My vise can rotate so I can position it so the vise lever hits the bench leaving enough above to slip the brake lever on to it. Also, a friend can simply hold the lever for you. You do need both hands--one to put some gentle pressure on the installed hose while the other manipulates the 8mmm wrench on the compression nut.

Number 3: Olives are one time use items. By design, they deform under the compression nut to fix the hose in place and seal the connection to handle high pressure tolerances. The extra olive and insert provided is for when or if you want to trim some length from the hose. The original insert will be cut off, and, if you've already installed the hose into the lever and tightened the compression nut, the prehinsttalled olive is used up. It will be fixed to the aspect of the hose that is gonna be trimmed anyway. Keep it for a future need if you're satisfied with the length which was initially installed into the lever.

Trimming the hose can be done successfully using a sharp blade. A good quality utility knife with a fresh razor blade works well. I use a sharp sheet metal shear (heavy duty scissors, essentially). The cut is very clean and due to the rigid quality of the hydraulic tubing and sharp shears, deformation of the tube doesn't occur. Whatever is used, a key point is that the end is cut clean and at 90 degrees to the hose lumen: a straight cut.

It will be helpful prior to installing the insert if you use something like a straight pick or small nail to sort of stretch the opening of the cut. The hydraulic hose is fairly rigid but can be stretched a little with a pick. The stretched hose does quickly contract back after a moment, so you should be prepared to install the insert immediately after reaming with the pick.  The insert will start easy enough but you will need a hammer to fully seat it this way. Several taps while holding the line firmly by hand usually does the trick on a pre-reamed line. A towel or something to enhance your grip on the line is helpful here. If a new olive is needed, it's usually helpful to have this and the compression nut slipped on before the insert is installed. Sometimes they don't want to go over the insert if it's installed first. They slide down and out of the way nicely otherwise. Don't forget the outer cover needs to be on before you tighten the hose into the lever.

As per Shimano directions, note the distance the olive should be positioned just prior to a post-trim  install. And grease the olive and the threads of the compression nut. When the lever is installed and the wheel with rotor is on or the pad spacer is installed in the caliper, manipulating the lever several times will firm up the brakes. The lever will feel stiffer after a few throws. If it remains soft after several throws, you may need at least a partial bleed. Most often, a bleed is not necessary when installing a new pre-bled system featuring the J-kit, even if the hose(s) need to be trimmed.